# Creating Confirmation message when a Delete button clicked on Asp.Net Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

i use this codes for a Delete button for a confirmation message :

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDelete" 
 OnClick="btnDelete_Click" 
 OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to delete the record ? ');" />
```

Here is the way to add confirm client script at server side :

```
btnDelete.Attributes.Add("onclick", 
    "return confirm('Do you want to delete the record ? ');")
```

but I'm getting the (Type Expected) error when debugging could anyone help please?
Thanks

Comment: Is this your first reference to `btnDelete`? How do you declare it? Is `btnDelete` nested in another control?

Comment: I dont get any error when i copy paste and test your code! is any other script call throws that error?

Comment: I guess the button is nested , otherwise the inline onClientClick handler would simply work.

Answer (score 2):

If you **already assigned** `OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to delete the record ? ');"`
**in your markup** you don't need add an attribute again. It **may** be the reason.

Comment out from server

```
//btnDelete.Attributes.Add("onclick", 
    "return confirm('Do you want to delete the record ? ');")
```

Answer (score 0):

The client side markup you have is correct and must work.

If you want to generate the JavaScript code from server side, then remove the related markup OnClientClick. You're duplicating client event handling.

Note: Instead of "onclick" attribute, consider using event attaching on page load (i.e.: using jquery).

Example:

```
$(".btn-delete").click(function() { /*do something here*/ });
```

Answer (score 0):

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)

```
    {
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                foreach (Button button in e.Row.Cells[12].Controls.OfType<Button>())

                {
                    if (button.CommandName == "Delete")
                    {
                        button.Attributes["onclick"] = "if(!confirm('Do you want to delete')){return false;};";
                    }

                }
```